# Brezis' exercise 6.5: $V$ is a Hilbert space and $V \subset \ell^2$ with compact injection

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, compact-operators

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive numbers with $\lim_n \lambda_n = \infty$. Let $V$ be the space of sequences $(u_n)_{n\ge 1}$ such that
> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n |u_n|^2 < \infty.
> $$
> The space $V$ is equipped with the inner product
> $$
> [u, v] := \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \lambda_n u_nv_n
> \quad \forall u,v \in V.
> $$
> Prove that $V$ is a Hilbert space and $V \subset \ell^2$ with compact injection.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We define a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb N^*$ by
$$
\mu (n) := \lambda_n
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.
$$

Then $V=L^2(\mathbb N^*, \mu, \mathbb R)$. Then $V$ together with $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is a Hilbert space. Because $\lim_n \lambda_n = \infty$, there is $N \in \mathbb N^*$ such that $\lambda_n \ge 1$ for $n \ge N$. Let $\alpha := \sup_{1 \le n \le N} \frac{1}{\lambda_n} < \infty$. Then for $u \in V$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n|^2 &= \sum_{n=1}^N |u_n|^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} |u_n|^2 \\
&\le \alpha \sum_{n=1}^N \lambda_n |u_n|^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \lambda_n |u_n|^2 \\
&\le (\alpha+1) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n |u_n|^2 .
\end{align}
$$

Then the linear injection $J:V \to \ell^2, (u_n) \mapsto (u_n)$ is continuous. Let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $V$. Let's prove that $J(B)$ has compact closure in $\ell^2$. Because $\ell^2$ is complete, it remains to prove that $J(B)$ is totally bounded in $\ell^2$. Let $|\cdot|_V$ and $|\cdot|_{\ell^2}$ be the corresponding norms of $V$ and $\ell^2$. Let $u = (u_n) \in B$ and $v = (v_n) \in B$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
|u|_V^2 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n |u_n|^2, \\
|Ju|_{\ell^2}^2 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n|^2.
\end{align}
$$

Fix $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$. Because $\lim_n \lambda_n = \infty$, there is $N \in \mathbb N^*$ such that $\lambda_n \ge \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ for $n \ge N$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \sum_{n=N}^\infty |u_n|^2 \le \sum_{n=N}^\infty \lambda_n |u_n|^2 \le 1.
$$

Then $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |u_n|^2 \le \varepsilon$ and thus $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |u_n -v_n|^2 \le 4\varepsilon$. It remains to control the set $C:=\{(x_n) \in B : x_n=0 \quad \forall n \ge N\}$. Clearly, $C$ is bounded in $\ell^2$ and contained in a finite-dimensional subspace, so $C$ is totally bounded $\ell^2$. This completes the proof.

---

**Update** I have added more explanation below.

Because $C$ is totally bounded, it has an $\varepsilon$-covering $\{x^1, \ldots, x^M\}$. We claim that $\{x^1, \ldots, x^M\}$ is a $5\varepsilon$-covering of $B$. Let $u = (u_n) \in B$. There is $x^k$ for some $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, M\}$ such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |x^k_n-u_n|^2 \le \varepsilon^2 \le \varepsilon.
$$

Because $x^k, u \in B$, we get $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |x^k_n-u_n|^2 \le 4\varepsilon$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
|x^k-u|_V^2 &= \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |x^k_n-u_n|^2 + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |x^k_n-u_n|^2 \\
&\le \varepsilon + 4\varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, $5\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily small.

Comment: (1) there is a typo in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty=\sum_{n=1}^N+\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}$
(2) I really don't see how you conclude total boundedness. What you have shown: if $\epsilon>0$ is fixed and $u,v\in B$ then there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ with $\sum_{n\ge N}|u_n-v_n|^2\le2\epsilon$. What then? The reference to $C$ does not make sense to me. You need to somehow demonstrate the existence of finitely many $\ell_2$-balls of size $\epsilon$ that cover $J(B)$.

Comment: @FShrike I have updated my thread with more details. Could you have a check on it?

Comment: That looks ok ${}$

Comment: @FShrike Thank you so much for your verification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the last part of the proof in the original post.  Here's another way of showing the compactness

Let $H=\ell^2(\Bbb{N}^+,\Bbb{C})$, $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ the standard basis of $H$ and $T:H\to H$ be defined by $T(v) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} \langle v, e_n\rangle e_n$.  $T$ is a multiplication operator.  It is bounded with $\|T\|=\max_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}$.

The range of $T$ is $V$ as defined in the original post.  $T$ by the formula defining it is a compact operator (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_spaces)), so the closure of $T(B)$ is compact in $H$.  If you want an explicit proof, Let $T_N(v) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} \langle v, e_n\rangle e_n$.  Then $T_N$ are finite rank and $\|T-T_N\| = \max_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$.  So $T$ is a norm limit of finite rank operators, and as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416046) it is compact.